# I plugged in a yubikey containing pgp subkeys, now secret key stubs are present

Tags: gnupg, yubikey

Procedure:

- Create keypair on a live distro, upload public key, move secret subkeys to Yubikey
- Reboot into normal disto
- Plug in yubikey, and then remove it
- Run `gpg --recv-keys HANDLE` to receive public key
- Run `gpg --list-secret-keys`.

The result is that the secret key *stubs* show up in the secret key list. Running `gpg --delete-secret-keys HANDLE` errors, because the keys are not present (only the stubs are present).

The secret key has 100% never been on this machine, so I'm not clear on why the stubs are here. Presumably they were automatically imported from the yubikey, but it seems odd that I can't delete them. Is this expected behaviour?

Further:

`gpg --delete-keys HANDLE` > Secret key stubs are gone

`gpg --recv-keys HANDLE` > Secret key stubs are back again

Comment: That looks normal to me. If you run `gpg --list-secret-keys` you should see the `>` character next to ssb, which indicates that the secret keys reside on a separate device, and not on the PC. The stubs are pointers.

Comment: @Anonymous thank you for confirming. I guess my question is why would a machine that has only downloaded the public key know that the secret keys are on a card? (The secret key has never been on this machine)

Comment: Afaik running `gpg --card-status` after plugging in the device (could be a smart card as well) is enough to import the stubs locally. It's possible that GPG Agent or even a GPG frontend is doing just that in the background.

Comment: @Anonymous Ah, that explains it, thank you. If you'd like to put that as an answer, I'll happily accept it

Comment: @Anonymous And the delete + re-import public key not clearing them is expected too?